# Loading multiple models in Python to do comparison between results of model

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, flask, keras, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to predict classes using two different models. 
These models are saved and loaded using a .json and .h5 file.

The problem I'm running into is that 50% of the time everything works fine, both models are correctly created and are able to do their predictions.

Half of the time there seems to go something wrong with the creation of the model(s) because then, when I try to predict something it gives me an error like this

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1_1' with dtype float and shape [?,10693]
 [[{{node input_1_1}} = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,10693], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Running both models separate/not at the same time works perfectly. No problems whatsoever.

After some googling I found that Keras keeps a global graph of the model(s) and this might cause the error. I feel like I have tried most of the suggestions I found online but I still can't seem to fix the problem of having two different models at the same time in a program.

So based on a given argument I want to either predict using model1, or model2:

```
def predict_using_cnn(text, model, tokenizer, to_predict):
if to_predict == 'functiegroep':
    with graph.as_default():
        sequences_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([text])
        X_test = pad_sequences(sequences_test, maxlen=6616)  # TODO fix this hardcoded thingy
        y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    return build_response(y_pred, to_predict)
elif to_predict == 'kernfunctie':
    with graph.as_default():
        sequences_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([text])
        X_test = pad_sequences(sequences_test, maxlen=10693)  # TODO fix this hardcoded thingy
        y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    return build_response(y_pred, to_predict)
```

This is where sometimes it goes intoe the first if statement thinking that it needs an input of 10693, which is the *other* model. So the program seems mix these things up at random.

Both models are loaded using the same function (ofcourse they are saved to two different variables)

```
def load_cnn_model(model_name):
print("loading" + str(model_name))
json_file = open(str(model_name) + '.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
model.load_weights(str(model_name) + '.h5')
return model
```

Anything to help me fix this problem is very much appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I eventually got it working like this:

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    session = tf.Session()
    with session.as_default():
        graph_fg = graph
        session_fg = session
        cnn_fg_model = predict.load_cnn_model('models/cnn/new_model_fg/new_model_fg')

with graph.as_default():
    session = tf.Session()
    with session.as_default():
        graph_kf = graph
        session_kf = session
        cnn_kf_model = predict.load_cnn_model('models/cnn/new_model_kf/new_model_kf')

with graph.as_default():
    with session.as_default():
        if to_predict == 'functiegroep':
            sequences_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([text])
            X_test = pad_sequences(sequences_test, maxlen=6616)  # TODO fix this hardcoded thingy
            y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
            return build_response_cnn(y_pred, to_predict)
        elif to_predict == 'kernfunctie':
            sequences_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([text])
            X_test = pad_sequences(sequences_test, maxlen=10693)  # TODO fix this hardcoded thingy
            y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
            return build_response_cnn(y_pred, to_predict)
```